# The tags [about-page] and [stackexchange-tour] should merge

Tags: discussion, status-completed, meta, retag-request, tour

The tags [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) and [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour) mean **exactly the same thing**:

The [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) tag's description:

> For questions relating to the Stack Exchange 'About' page, now also referred to as the 'tour' for new users.

The [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour) tag's description:

> The Stack Exchange tour contains an introduction to Stack Exchange. It can be accessed through the help menu in the top bar. Use this tag for questions about using this tour.

***These are very clearly referring to the same thing and should merge.***

Answer (score 5):

### Merge [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) into [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour), and rename it to [site-tour](/questions/tagged/site-tour)

I agree with your suggestion; both tags are clearly asking about the same thing.

Currently, plenty of the questions with the [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) tag are explicitly asking about the site tour. (I'm sure it helps that this tag has [tour](/questions/tagged/tour) as a synonym of it.) Judging from the tag wikis, both tags describe the exact same topic.

Specifically, I think [about-page](/questions/tagged/about-page) should be merged into [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour), since the page is currently called the "tour" page.

---

Personally, I think the tag should ultimately end up being called [site-tour](/questions/tagged/site-tour) instead, since it's a simpler name but still pretty unambiguous. (Right now, [site-tour](/questions/tagged/site-tour) is a synonym of [stackexchange-tour](/questions/tagged/stackexchange-tour), but that relationship could easily be flipped.)

Comment: (If folks feel differently about what the tag should end up being called, feel free to leave a separate answer so the community can vote accordingly.)

Comment: It's worth mentioning these 2 posts and the 2 tag wikis don't have a link to the page they refer to. TBH it's unclear to me what page we are talking about.

Comment: ...Looks like both tags have now been merged into [tour] (which has [about-page] and [site-tour] as synonyms) and there's no longer a tag by the name of [stackexchange-tour], so I guess I'll mark this as completed.. It looks like Glorfindel has edited that tag wiki to include a link to the tour page and an explanation of how to find the tour page on every site.